# appcelerator get-chat group showing all groups not just the one logged in user is in

Tags: chat, appcelerator

I need help on tiny issue for developing an app using appcelerator cloud.

I want to show ONLY the list of chat groups(using table view) the logged in user is involved with.
But somehow, it is showing all the chat group.
And when i clikc each row, I cant seem to proceed to the chat page where the actual chat messages are,,,

thanx in advance for your help?

```
Cloud.Chats.getChatGroups({

        // i thinkg this is where i need help, this query with 'where' part
        where : {
        participate_users : { "$in" : user}
        }
},
    function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        if (e.chat_groups.length == 0) {
                table.setData([
                    { title: 'No Results!' }
                ]);
            }
        var tbl_data = []; 
        for (var i = 0; i < e.chat_groups.length; i++) {
            var group = e.chat_groups[i];

             //some code

            tbl_data.push(row);
        }
        var table = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
            data:tbl_data
        });
        table.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                 //some code defining 'groudid'
                var loginwin,loginInc;
                    loginInc = require('conversation');
                    loginwin = new loginInc.convo(groudid);
                    loginwin.open();
                loginwin.open();
            });
        chatview.add(table);
    } else {
        alert('Error:\n' +
            ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

Comment: Without additional info it's impossible to help. Is user a model object? Try something like "user.get('id')" in where clause